# cordova-plugin-qrscanner not showing up in ios

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I used cordova-plugin-qrscanner for my ionic 2 application. When i click on a tab the scanner will be opened. It works perfectly in android, but in ios the camera is not shown on the screen but it scans blindly. When i change the orientation of the screen the camera is displayed properly. 
I tried to reload the page using`window.location.reload()` but it didnt work.
Thanks in advance.